# when to create a weblogic domain

Tags: weblogic9.x

I have two web applications deployed in two different weblogic servers.

Application 1 is a struts 1.2 based application whereas Application 2 is a JSF application.

We are working towards deploying both the application on the same weblogic server.

Wanted to know if it would be better to deploy the two application ears on the same weblogic domain or create different domains for each of the ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on a lot of things, but a couple of questions might help getting you into the right direction:

- Does the same person/group of persons administer/deploy both applications?
- Do both of your applications have the same security model/constraints?

Typically, if you answer *no* to one of the questions above, you should probably go ahead and configure a separate domain for each one.
Other kinds of constraints might also affect your decision, like whether your applications interact/depend on each other, or if they share any underlying resources.

I have personally run several applications which were all administered by me, shared the same security model and depended on similar underlying resources. I had them all in a single WebLogic domain. That would be my recommendation, in order to simplify administrative tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Viccari.In my case both the applications use weblogic 9.2 and have more or less similar kind of functionality.The only difference is the technology in which they are implemented.The need of the hour is to deploy these applications on the same weblogic so as to save the server cost without getting any surprises in future.I wanted to know if deploying multiple ears on the same weblogic affect the performance of the applications.I would really appreciate if you could share a few challenges you faced during maintaining different application ears on the same weblogic domain.

Comment: Your environment is similar to what mine was in the past. When we started to come into scale issues, we added a second server (also with both applications) and a load balancer in front of them. This approach has also more fault tolerance than if you had two servers, one hosting each application. Of course, if your applications do not share the same deployment and security models, and the same administrator, I would not follow this path.